# A question on convergence in Sobolev norm and isolated discontinuties.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ with a smooth boundary. Consider the space $M = \{f/f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R} and \lvert|f\rvert|_{W^{1,N+1}} \in \mathbb{R}^+\} \setminus I $, where $I$ is the set of all functions that have atleast one isolated discontinuty. Consider any sequence $\{f_n\}$ where $f_n\in M$. Can we say that the following is true?

If $f_n \to f$ in the norm $\lvert|.\rvert|_{W^{1,N+1}}$ then $f\in M$.

Comment: Every function in $W^{1,N+1}(\Omega)$ is continuous. Hence, $M = W^{1,N+1}(\Omega)$, isn't it?

Comment: @Gerw : I am talking about isolated discontinuties! These can be brought into $W^{1,N+1}(\Omega)$ by simply modifying values on a set of measure zero!

Comment: @Gerw : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361506/2987

Comment: @Gerw : Please dont fiddle with definitions. Answer my question in its spirit. I am asking this question, because I have a reason to distinguish between functions that dont agree on a set of measure zero!

Comment: First, your *terminology* is wrong: An isolated discontinuity is a discontinuity that is the only discontinuity in some neighbourhood. You are thinking of something more akin to *removable* discontinuities. Second, your question contains a category error: A Sobolev space is a set of *equivalence classes* of functions, whereas your set $I$ is a set of *functions*. Thus $I$ cannot be a subset of any Sobolev space. This renders the question meaningless and hence unanswerable.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen : Correcting it. Thanks.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen : Can you please check if it makes sense now?, the definition.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, and the answer is a resounding **no**. Hang on, I'll write it up. (The terminology problem with “isolated” discontinuites remains, though.)

Comment: If you choose not to identify functions that agree a.e., then $\lvert| \cdot \rvert|_{W^{1,N+1}}$ is **not** a norm (because a lot of different functions would have zero norm). In consequence, convergence or topology induced by this seminorm are bad-behaved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For a trivial example, let $f_n=0$ for all $n$, and let $f$ be zero almost everywhere, but not identically zero.

Comment: Hang on. Let me revise my  definition to include zero function. This hurry of yours is ruining the question.

Comment: It won't help. Just take $g$ to be any continuous Sobolev function replace $f_n$ by $g$, and  $f$ by $g$ modified on a set of measure zero.

Comment: Okay, we need to talk only in terms of equivalence classes, in the sense if  we want to prove a point about a limit function (converging in this norm), its basically is not just function but a equivalence class, and to show that it satisfies a property, we just show that there is atleast one representative in this equivalance class that satisfies the desired propery. Thanks @Harald. And pardon me if was offensive.

Comment: No, you weren't offensive, just confused. But that appears to be cleared up now. That's good.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2363683/2987 This is what I am hunting for, and you helped me formulate it better. posting the link here, hoping someone will take a shot at it.