# Aren't functions in Sobolev spaces defined only upto a set of measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Aren't functions in Sobolev spaces defined only upto a set of measure zero? I see some people on math.SE arguing all the functions of the form $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega$ is a convex open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, they say if $f\in W^{1,N+1}$, then by default $f$ is continuous inside $\Omega$. I agree $f$ cannot have jump discontinuities, but what about isolated discontinuities? especially given that functions in Sobolev spaces are defined only upto a set of measure zero? I am really confused between these contradicting definitions and facts.

Comment: You are correct that they are only defined up to sets of measure zero but we typically brush this fact under the rug. When we talk about a function $f$ in a Sobolev space, we are really talking about the equivalence class $[f]$ so when we say that such a function is continuous, we mean that there is a function in the equivalence class which is continuous.

Comment: @User8128 : I have a problem which is very sensitive to this brush off. I have to define a Sobolev space but in the course of the problem, I have to differentiate between functions even if dont agree on a set of measure zero. How can I name such a space. I have to define this space as jsut functions whose Sobolev norm is finite. I had asked a recent question of mine and came under pressure due to this fact and deleted that question. Can someone please undelete that question of mine.

Comment: It is Here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361235/2987 Can you ressurect this brush off by Gerw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Sobolev functions are in $L^p$ so they are not functions but equivalence classes $[f]$ of functions. However, if $p>N$ then Morrey's theorem says that there is a representative in the equivalence class $[f]$ of a Sobolev function which is Holder's continuous.

Comment: Can you please undelete a question of mine I had just deleted, if you have the power. It is very much relevant to this fact and I had to delete it under pressure.

Comment: I don't have that power, sorry!

Comment: It is here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2361235/2987

Comment: Can you ressurect this brush off by Gerw

Comment: I saw your post. If you have a function $f\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$, then $f$ belongs to $W^{1,N+1}(\Omega)$, so you can consider its equivalence class $[f]$ and it is true that you can modify it to make it discontinuous, but why would you want to do that? If you have a nice function, you keep it as it is, you don't change the representative to make it worse.

Comment: Believe it or not, I have a special problem, where I have to differentiate functions that don't agree on a set of measure zero. So I have to be cautious of this fact. Did you not get the question I am asking there? does it not have a logical answer other than fidling with definitions?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not fiddling with definitions. I did read your question but your set $I$ does not make sense in a Sobolev setting, exactly beacuse functions are defined a.e. Maybe you should explain what your original problem is or expand your original question to explain better what your set $I$ is.

Comment: Okay, Let me define that set as functions of the form $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert | f\rvert|_{W^{1,N+1}}$ is finite, rather than than just the set $W^{1,N+1}$, as the later is an equivalence, and then go on ..., would that avoid the confusion?

Comment: Are you talking about that other question now? If so, that seems the right place to discuss it.

Comment: @Gio67 : Sorry if I soundd offensive. I got he point. Thank you very much for the nice answer.

Comment: no worries. Glad it is clear now.